# Checking for IEnumerable<T> with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, valueinjecter

**EDIT**

The bare-bones version of this question is, if I have some `object o`, how would I check to see if o is of some type that implements `IEnumerable<string>` **with reflection**?  The original question is much more specific, but an answer to the above would be just as good.  Sorry if I gave *too much* detail on this question

**END EDIT**

The following is a contrived ValueInjecter POC.  Everything works well except for the `isCollectionMapping` method at the very bottom.  I'm trying to get it to return true if and only if both the source and target property are any object that implement `IEnumerable<respectiveTypes>`.

I've tried `IsAssignableFrom` and also `IsInstanceOfType`, but neither seems to work.

Everything else works since when I uncomment the second line of the method to check explicitly for properties of name "Children", it works fine.

**Note** - I do know there are issues with this example.  Namely, I'm trying to check for any old `IEnumerable<>` but yet always knowing enough to return `List<>`; it's just a silly proof of concept at this point.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        Subject S = new Subject() {
            id = 1,
            SubjectName = "S1",
            Children = { new Subject() { id = 2, SubjectName = "S1a" },
                         new Subject() { id = 3, SubjectName = "S1b", Children = { new Subject() { id = 4} } } }
        };

        SubjectViewModel VM = (SubjectViewModel)new SubjectViewModel().InjectFrom<CollectionToCollection>(S); ;


        Assert.AreEqual(2, VM.Children.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, VM.Children.Single(s => s.id == 3).Children.Count);
    }
}


public class Subject {
    public Subject() {
        Children = new List<Subject>();
    }

    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> Children { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectViewModel {
    public SubjectViewModel() {
        Children = new List<SubjectViewModel>();
    }

    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

    public List<SubjectViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionToCollection : Omu.ValueInjecter.ConventionInjection {
    protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c) {
        return c.TargetProp.Name == c.SourceProp.Name;
    }

    protected override object SetValue(ConventionInfo c) {
        if (isCollectionMapping(c))
            return (c.SourceProp.Value as IEnumerable<Subject>).Select(s => (SubjectViewModel)(new SubjectViewModel().InjectFrom<CollectionToCollection>(s))).ToList();
        else
            return c.SourceProp.Value;
    }

    private bool isCollectionMapping(ConventionInfo c) {
        return c.SourceProp.Value.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IEnumerable<Subject>)) && c.TargetProp.Value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<SubjectViewModel>));

        //return c.SourceProp.Name == "Children" && c.TargetProp.Name == "Children";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> If I have some object `o`, how would I
>   check to see if `o` is of some type that
>   implements `IEnumerable<string>`?

As simple as:

```
o is IEnumerable<string>
```

By the way, your current code isn't working because it is *reversing* the testing of the assignability relationship (as though the method were called `IsAssignableTo`), i.e.  It is assuming that:

```
Bar bar = ...
Foo foo = bar
```

implies:

```
typeof(Bar).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Foo)) // wrong
```

In reality, the actual implication is that:

```
typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Bar))
```

> Namely, I'm trying to check for any
>   old `IEnumerable<>`:

In this case, you need to test if the type implements a constructed version of the generic interface:

```
o.GetType()
 .GetInterfaces()
 .Any(t => t.IsGenericType 
        && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
```

Comment: Be careful to remember that string type is IEnumerable

Answer (score 10):

> The bare-bones version of this question is, if I have some object o, how would I check to see if o is of some type that implements `IEnumerable<string>`?

Like this:

```
object o = whatever;
bool isSequenceOfStrings = o is IEnumerable<string>;
```

Comment: I seem to really have a hard time striking a balance between too much information, and too little.  I need to do it with reflection.  Sorry for the confusion, Eric.  :)

Comment: @Adam: Then what is the question? Is the question "If I have some Type object t how would I check to see if t implements IEnumerable<string>?" Or is the question "If I have some type object t then how would I check if t is IEnumerable<string>?" Or is the question "If I have some type object t then how would I check if T is convertible to IEnumerable<string??" or "... is equal to IEnumerable<T> for any T?" or... Those are all different questions. You'll get the answer you want when you ask the question you actually are interested in .

Comment: Why do you need to do it with reflection?

Comment: The entire question—after my edit—lists out the situation, and why I need reflection.  Upon reading the question back to myself, I thought it may have been a bit long given how simple the problem was, so I added the edit at the beginning.  I ended up making things more confusing, not less.  Edit-fail.

Comment: When I look at the code sample, I see you testing c.SourceProp.Value against a literal interface implementation (IEnumerable<Subject>). This doesn't seem to require reflection. c.SourceProp.Value is IEnumerable<Subject> returns the same result, does it not?

Comment: If you are using unknown types (the usual case for reflection), you could still chose to wrap these in a nested class of a generic type, which could allow you to avoid reflection.

Comment: @Adam: Looking at your code, I don't understand why you feel that you need to use reflection. What is wrong with "(c.SourceProp.Value is IEnumerable<Subject>) && (c.TargetProp.Value is IEnumerable<SubjectViewModel>)" ???

Comment: Nothing.  I was wrong to assume I needed reflection.  I guess we've come full circle, and my edit, and your answer turned out to be accurate.  I hope this question doesn't reflect how the rest of this day will go :-\

Answer (score 4):

I could have missed something (didn't read your whole code sample), but it doesn't seem like you need reflection here.

How about just using:

```
if (c.SourceProp.Value is IEnumerable<Subject>)
   return true;
```

If you don't know the specific type, use generics:

```
public bool MyFunction<T>(...)
{
   if (c.SourceProp.Value is IEnumerable<T>)
      return true;
}
```

Or if you need to use the interface, do it this way (saves a cast):

```
var enumerable = c.SourceProp.Value as IEnumerable<string>;
if (enumerable != null)
{
   // Use IEnumerable<string>
   return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, the simple is would have worked.  Not sure how I missed that.  +1